# how to get the data from serial port (RS-232) on client side

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, com, serial-port

My project i'm doing now is getting the weigh from the scale that use RS-232 port and post it into the website then press submit and the data will be saved into the server.
I also study how to get the value from these port using the java API called javax.comm. However, I think it just work on the server, and could be work for one computer. that's the problem. therefore, I want to make a website that the client computer can access to the website and weigh the scale then save it into the server. So, how can we do it? Does javascript work on it?

thanks :)

Comment: Need to build a plugin with flash or Java. Most browsers won't allow javascript to do this.

Comment: you could also do a Firefox plugin

Comment: how to make a plugin, which language we can use? can we build it on chrome, my website works well on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Of course you amy do this with a browser plugin, but that will make the application browser specific. Instead what you may do it to create a simple desktop agent (windows service, taskbar app) that will be installed on the client machine itself.

Now this agent should respond to HTTP requests from your web page that are directed to http://[localhost]:[port]. This might need to embed a simple HTTP server inside the agent. The other complexity you will have to handle is on Cross Origin Requests. You may either use JSONp OR CORS in handling that.